# Find lowest value for each row of db - sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Ive got a table of price info as the image below, im trying to query the db to give me back the 'item' and the cheapest supplier value.

[image: data base values]

So for the table below it would be

- bike, Supplier 3 - 120.43
- shoe, Supplier 2 - 19.99
- ball, Supplier 1 - 5.50

Is this possible to do with sql querys, or would you need to output all the values and then filter them with php (or language of choice) ?

Comment: That is a poor schema for doing what you want.  What if there were a thousand suppliers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: As Wallyk mentioned this is not a good schema design.  Breakout supplier to another table.  Then you have a product table.  The you have a pricing table which has a foreign key to product and supplier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [LEAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

```
select item, least(supplier1, supplier2, supplier3)
from your_table
```

Comment: Does SQLite support LEAST() ?

Comment: Perhaps there is an equivalent, just named differently. I couldn't find one though.

Answer (score 1):

Change your schema.

Table `suppliers`

```
supplier_id    supplier_name
1              Supplier 1
2              Supplier 2
3              Supplier 3
```

Table `products`

```
product_id     product_name
1              Bike
2              Shoe
3              Ball
```

Table `prices`

```
product_id     supplier_id     price
1              1               125.65
1              2               132.01
1              3               120.43
2              1               23.99
2              2               19.99
2              3               25.96
3              1               5.50
3              2               8.65
3              3               6.50
```

Your query

```
SELECT product_name, supplier_name, price
FROM prices
INNER JOIN products ON products.product_id = prices.product_id
INNER JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.supplier_id = prices.supplier_id
GROUP BY prices.product_id
HAVING price = MIN(prices.price)
```